# ISQL 7.3 Perform screens with 132-columns

Tags: informix

If I change SuSE's terminfo to 132-column (co#132) and in my Perform .per code specify 
SCREEN SIZE 24 BY 132, would I be able to fit more field tags past the 80-column mark and it display them properly?.. I want to cram more stuff into one screen without having to split it up into separate screens. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set `INFORMIXTERM=terminfo` so Perform uses Terminfo, then yes, what you suggest should work.  It is a long while since I last did this, but it worked back in the early '90s on real green (or orange) screens - like Wyse 60 terminals.